# Laravel pines notify buttons not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I've managed to integrate Pines Notify in Laravel 4.

**1st problem:**

There is no remove button for a notification.

Here's an example of a code:

```
     @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

  $.pnotify({
    title: 'Success!',
    text: '{{ $message }}',
    type: 'info',
    icon: false
  });

@endif
```

**2nd problem:**

Second of all, I've reviewed some stacks on Pines Notify site. How do I use them with Laravel? I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
     @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

  $.pnotify({
    function show_stack_bottomleft(type) {
    title: 'Success!',
    text: '{{ $message }}',
    type: 'info',
    icon: false
  }
  });

@endif
```

Comment: is the js file included correctly? do you get any error? check the console, maybe it has an error or it is missing something

Comment: @LeventeNagy nope, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
@if ($message == Session::get('success'))

  $.pnotify({
    title: 'Success!',
    text: '{{ $message }}',
    type: 'info',
    icon: false
  });

@endif
```

You have missed the "==" in if operator.

Comment: The site doesn't work if I have two '='s in the the if operator.

Comment: can you please post `dd($message);` and `dd(Session::get('success'))` over here. -or- post the code [link](http://paste.laravel.com)